# Delphi: Try to find open TCP ports but doesn't detect any open port

Tags: windows, delphi, sockets, ports

I have two processes that must run on two free TCP ports on the PC. This must be a painless out-of-the-box process for it's user, I want to auto detect free ports to avoid conflicts and apply these port numbers to these two processes.

To achieve this, I made a function (that runs in a thread also) to detect the free ports but doesn't find any free ports. Can somebody explain what is wrong with my code?

**EDIT: The solution provided by "@500-error etc" is applied to the code. Function now working OK.**

Here it is:

```
    uses
     winsock;

    type
     TAvailablePortArray = array of Word;

function findAvailableTCPPort( ipAddressStr : String; portStart : Word = 8080; portEnd : Word = 8084; findCount : Byte = 2 ) : TAvailablePortArray;
var
  client    : sockaddr_in;
  sock      : Integer;
  ret       : Integer;
  wsdata    : WSAData;
  dwPort    : Word;
  iFound    : Byte;
  bResult   : Boolean;
  bAllFound : Boolean;
  dns       : PHostEnt;
  status    : LongInt;


begin
 setLength( Result, 0 );
 if( portStart > portEnd ) or ( portStart = 0 ) or ( findCount = 0 ) then
  Exit;

 try
 ret := WSAStartup($0002, wsdata); //initiates use of the Winsock DLL
 except
  ret:=-1;
 end;

 if( ret <> 0 ) then
  Exit;

 dns:=getHostByName( PChar(ipAddressStr) );
 if( NOT Assigned( dns )) then
  Exit;

 bResult:=TRUE;
 try
  fillChar( client, sizeOf( client ), 0 );
  client.sin_family      := AF_INET;  //Set the protocol to use , in this case (IPv4)
  client.sin_addr.s_addr :=LongInt(PLongInt(dns^.h_addr_list^)^);
  //inet_addr(PAnsiChar(ipAddressStr));  //convert to IN_ADDR  structure
 except
  bResult:=FALSE;
 end;

 if( bResult ) then
 begin
  dwPort:=portStart;
  setLength( Result, findCount );
  bAllFound:=FALSE;
  iFound:=0;

  while( NOT bAllFound ) and ( dwPort <= portEnd ) do
  begin
   try
    client.sin_port:=htons(dwPort); //convert to TCP/IP network byte order (big-endian)
    sock:=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP );    //creates a socket
    Application.processMessages();
    status:=connect(sock,client,sizeOf(client));
    bResult:=(status <> 0); //establishes a connection to a specified socket, less than zero is NOT in use
   except
    bResult:=FALSE;
   end;

   if( sock <> 0 ) then
   begin
    closesocket(sock);
    sock:=0;
   end; 

   if( bResult ) then
   begin
    Result[iFound]:=dwPort;
    inc( iFound );
    bAllFound:=( iFound = findCount );
   end;

   inc(dwPort);
  end;
 end;

 if( NOT bAllFound ) then
  setLength( Result, 0 );

 try
  WSACleanup();
 except;
 end;
end;
```

Some code to call the function above:

```
procedure TForm1.btStartClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 addLogMsg( 'Starting service ...' );
 FPorts:=findAvailableTCPPort( '127.0.0.1' );
 FPortCount:=Length( FPorts );
 addLogMsg( 'Available ports found: '+strToInt( FPortCount ));

 if( FPortCount < 2 ) then
 begin
  addLogMsg( 'ERROR: Cannot start service(s), insufficient free ports!' );
  Exit;
 end;
 ................
 ................
 ................
end;
```

What I am doing wrong?

NOTE: I have debug the code, the process seems to be OK (it tries to test it, no exceptions). Also verified that the ports specified are not in use by testing it with other app.

Comment: `socket()` returns `INVALID_SOCKET` (-1) on error, not 0.

Comment: About downvoting: Sometimes I don't understand the people at SO, why downvote my question, why??????? Bad hairday?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I (now) believe the issue is that you are misinterpreting the result from `connect`.

If `connect` succeeds (returns zero), it means that the port is in use.

Comment: Your solution is not rockin' science but you are right! Thanks. When it is not connected, it returns -1. Do you know the excactly meaning of this code?

Comment: See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737625(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You went around this the wrong way.  You should be using `bind()` instead of `connect()`.  If a port is already in use, `bind()` will fail.  No need to attempt to `connect()` to a separate IP. For example:

```
uses
  winsock;

type
  TAvailablePortArray = array of Word;

function findAvailableTCPPort( const ipAddressStr : AnsiString; portStart : Word = 8080; portEnd : Word = 8084; findCount : Byte = 2 ) : TAvailablePortArray;
var
  client    : sockaddr_in;
  sock      : TSocket;
  wsdata    : WSAData;
  dwPort    : Word;
  iFound    : Byte;
  bResult   : Boolean;
  arrFound  : TAvailablePortArray;
begin
  SetLength( Result, 0 );
  if ( portStart = 0 ) or ( portStart > portEnd ) or ( findCount = 0 ) then
    Exit;

  //initiates use of the Winsock DLL
  if ( WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), wsdata) <> 0 ) then
    Exit;

  try
    //Set the protocol to use , in this case (IPv4)
    fillChar( client, sizeOf( client ), 0 );
    client.sin_family      := AF_INET;
    client.sin_addr.s_addr := inet_addr(PAnsiChar(ipAddressStr));

    dwPort := portStart;
    SetLength( arrFound, findCount );
    try
      iFound := 0;

      repeat
        sock := socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);    //creates a socket
        if sock = INVALID_SOCKET then Break;

        try
          if GetQueueStatus(QS_ALLINPUT) <> 0 then
            Application.ProcessMessages();

          client.sin_port := htons(dwPort); //convert to TCP/IP network byte order (big-endian)

          if bind(sock, PSockAddr(@client)^, sizeOf(client)) = 0 then
          begin
            arrFound[iFound] := dwPort;
            Inc( iFound );
          end;
        finally
          closesocket(sock);
        end;

        Inc(dwPort);
      until ( iFound = findCount ) or ( dwPort > portEnd );
    finally
      SetLength(arrFound, iFound);
    end;
  finally
    WSACleanup();
  end;

  Result := arrFound;
end;
```

Alternatively, forget using sockets at all.  Enumerate through Windows' TCP/UDP tables instead, which list the active ports in use.  Look at [`GetTcpTable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366026.aspx), [`GetTcp6Table()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb309068.aspx), [`GetUdpTable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366033.aspx), and [`GetUdp6Table()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408407.aspx).

With that said, either approach is fundamentally flawed, because both approaches have a race condition - after the function finds the available ports, someone else could come along and open the ports before your processes can.  The best option is to simply have each process `bind()` itself to port 0 unconditionally and let the OS pick an available port at that moment, and then the two processes can announce their designated ports if needed.

Comment: If I use bind, result is always zero. When I check WSAGetLastError the return value is never WSAEADDRINUSE when port is in use. So do i miss something inhere?

Comment: When `bind()` returns zero, it means the specified port was available for use and is now assigned to the bound socket. `WSAGetLastError()` is only meaningful when errors occur.

Comment: Not a true story. The bind function returns always zero, no matter what. Tested with some servers running on specified ports and without, same result, always.

Comment: I assure you, `bind()` cannot bind to a port that is already in use. It will report `WSAEADDRINUSE`. About the only way that would not happen is if you are enabling the `SO_REUSEADDR` option, which you should not be doing if you are.

Comment: Hello Remy, tested your function but it is not working. It tells me that port 8080 is free but it isn't.

Comment: If `bind()` is able to bind to port 8080 without error then 8080 is free for use. If 8080 is actually in use, then either it is not using TCP (maybe UDP for instance) or more likely is open on a different network adapter than the one you are trying to bind to. Keep in mind that port assignments are both protocol-dependant and adapter-dependant. It is possible to have different protocols open the same port on the same adapter, and to have the same protocol open the same port on different adapters, without causing conflicts. `bind()` does not lie. If it binds without error, then it really bound.

Comment: Dude, i understand what you are saying but it still doesn't work and yes it runs on TCP. Other question, why do you change the original code that much, I don't see there is a clear reason to reformat the whole function for one little change, changing connect into bind and the way how to check the result.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30153/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-erwinus)